# Why does xml.dom.minidom walk to remove empty text nodes work unexpectedly?

Tags: python, xml, tree-traversal, minidom

The Code: (usual depth-first)

```
import xml.dom.minidom as xdom    

def _walk_n_apply(func, cond, parent):                                                                                                                                                          
    if parent.childNodes:                                                                                                                                                                       
       for child in parent.childNodes:                                                                                                                                                          
            if cond(child):                                                                                                                                                                    
                func(parent, child)                                                                                                                                                              
                continue                                                                                                                                                                      
            _walk_n_apply(func, cond, child)                                                                                                                                                   

def remove_child(parent, child):                                                                                                                                                                 
    node = parent.removeChild(child)                                                                                                                                                             
    print 'removed', node                                                                                                                                                                     

def is_empty_text_node(node):                                                                                                                                                                 
    return node.nodeType == node.TEXT_NODE and node.data.strip() == ''   


xmldom = xdom.parse('blah')

_walk_n_apply(remove_child, is_empty_text_node, xmldom)
```

In Ipython, upon calling

```
_walk_n_apply(remove_child, is_empty_text_node, xmldom)
```

once, there is **slight** change in the output:

```
print xmldom.toprettyxml()
```

but, if I call it several times, "several depending on the level of nesting", it eventually gives out a nicely formatted `prettyxml`.

How do I achieve this with a single call?

---

Input file contents:

```
<grammar xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org/2001/06/grammar
                             http://www.w3.org/TR/speech-grammar/grammar.xsd"
         xml:lang="en" version="1.0"
         root="command"
         mode="voice"
         tag-format="semantics/1.0">

<rule id="command">
   <one-of>
      <item><ruleref uri="#announcement" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#hello" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#whereis" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#interrupt" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#message" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#logon" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#logoff" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#storecoverage" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#identify" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#near" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#time" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#playmessages" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#registerbackup" /></item>
      <item><ruleref uri="#igotit" /></item>
   </one-of>
   <tag>out=rules.latest()</tag>
</rule>

<rule id="announcement">
<item>
  <one-of>
   <item>announcement today<tag>out="AnnouncementToday"</tag></item>
   <item>announcement now<tag>out="AnnouncementNow"</tag></item>
   <item>announcement hour<tag>out="AnnouncementHour"</tag></item>
  </one-of>
</item>
</rule>

<rule id="hello">
  <item repeat="0-1">
    <one-of>
        <item>hello</item>
        <item>hey</item>
        <item>hi</item>
    </one-of>
   </item>
   <item><ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/><tag>out="Hello,"+rules.latest()</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="whereis">
  <item>
   <one-of>
      <item>where is<ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/></item>
      <item>locate<ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/></item>
      <item>find<ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/></item>
   </one-of>
   <tag>out="Whereis,"+rules.latest()</tag>
  </item>
</rule>

<rule id="interrupt">
   <item>interrupt<ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/><tag>out="Interrupt,"+rules.latest()</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="message">
<item>message</item>
  <item repeat="0-1">for</item>
   <item><ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/><tag>out="Message,"+rules.latest()</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="logon">
   <one-of>
    <item>log on
       <one-of>
        <item><ruleref uri="persons.grxml"/><tag>out="Logon,"+rules.latest()</tag></item>
        <item><ruleref uri="#id_numbers"/><tag>out="Logon,"+rules.latest()</tag></item>
       </one-of>
        </item>
   </one-of>
</rule>

<rule id="logoff">
<item>
  <one-of>
      <item>log off<item repeat='0-1'>system</item></item>
      <item>log out</item>
  </one-of>
  <tag>out="Logoff"</tag>
</item>
</rule>

<rule id="storecoverage">
   <item repeat="0-1">store</item>
    <item>coverage<tag>out="coverage"</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="identify">
   <item>identify<tag>out="identify"</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="near">
    <one-of>
      <item>who is</item>
      <item>anyone</item>
    </one-of>
  <item>near<ruleref uri="#locations"/><tag>out="near,"+rules.latest()</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="time">
<one-of>
    <item>time<tag>out="time"</tag></item>
    <item>what time is it<tag>out="time"</tag></item>
</one-of>
</rule>

<rule id="playmessages">
  <item>
    play
   <one-of>
      <item>messages<tag>out="PlayMessages"</tag></item>
      <item>announcements<tag>out="PlayMessages"</tag></item>
   </one-of>
  </item>
</rule>

<rule id="registerbackup">
   <item repeat="0-1">cash</item>
    <item>register backup<tag>out="register backup"</tag></item>
</rule>

<rule id="igotit">
 <one-of>
   <item>
    <one-of>
     <item>i got it<tag>out="i got it"</tag></item>
     <item>i have it<tag>out="i got it"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
   </item>
   <item>
    <one-of>
     <item>on the way<tag>out="i got it"</tag></item>
     <item>on my way<tag>out="i got it"</tag></item>
    </one-of>
   </item> 
 </one-of>
</rule>


<rule id="locations">
   <ruleref uri="locations.grxml"/>
   <tag>out=rules.latest();</tag>
</rule>
```

Output if I call the function only once:

```
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
```

Output if I iteratively call the function 10 times:

like so

```
for i in range(10):
    _walk_n_apply(remove_child, is_empty_text_node, xmldom)
```

(output is copy-pasted from a tmux session, so there could be a few lines missed; the what I lack in understanding is that if my function is recursive and correct, it should have done away with all the empty-text nodes in one call. But calling it the second time also results in some more empty text nodes being removed, and then the third time, and so on... till there are no more empty-text nodes left.)

```
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">                                                                                                                                                       
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">                                                                                                                                                       
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">                                                                                                                                                     
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u' \n '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">                                                                                                                                                    
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n'">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n        '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n        '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n        '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n        '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n        '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n       '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n        '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n      '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n  '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n   '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n     '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n     '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n     '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n     '">
removed <DOM Text node "u'\n    '">
```

Comment: Please provide a sample input and the expected and actual results of running your code on that sample input.

Comment: @Robᵩ I have edited the question with sample input file and output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are manipulating the list of children while you are iterating `.childNodes`. Try this:

```
for child in list(parent.childNodes):
```